# BSE India best data source for foreigners (Bloomberg terminal?)

Tags: market-data, bloomberg, tick-data

I'm looking for a best possible data source for BSE India realtime L2 data (at least 5 levels of book) equities only (F&O welcome, but not needed).

I have an access to bloomberg terminal, have you any experience with its data quality? (Max 1 second delay, 200ms ideal)

As I have discovered India is quite restrictive in terms of data availability for foreigners.

Comment: I think your best bet is to contact them: http://www.bseindia.com/products_and_services/product_pricing.aspx?expandable=0

Comment: @AK88 Excellent point! Did not find it during own research. Thank you.